# an iterator that constructs a new object on dereference

Tags: c++11, iterator

I have a Visual Studio 2013 C++11 project where I'm trying to define an iterator. I want that iterator to dereference to an object, but internally it actually iterates over some internal data the object requires for construction.

```
class my_obj
{
public:
    my_obj(some_internal_initialization_value_ v);

    std::wstring friendly_name() const;
    // ...
};

class my_iterator 
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
        my_iterator,
        my_obj,
        boost::forward_traversal_tag>
{
    // ...
private:
    my_obj& dereference() const
    {
        // warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary
        return my_obj(some_internal_initialization_value_);
    }
};

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
    my_container c;
    for (auto o = c.begin(); o != c.end(); ++o)
        printf( "%s\n", o->friendly_name().c_str() );
}
```

These internal values are unimportant implementation details to the user and I'd prefer not to expose them. How can I write the iterator that does this correctly? The alternative is that I would have to do something like this:

```
my_container c;
for (auto i = c.begin(); i != c.end(); ++i)
{
    my_obj o(*i);
    printf( "%s\n", o.friendly_name().c_str() );
}
```

Comment: What happens if you change that to `my_obj dereference() const`?

Comment: You must return `my_obj` by value, not by reference. Also, `my_obj` needs to implement `operator->` which simply returns `this`. Then `my_iterator::operator->` would also return a new instance of `my_obj`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I don't think `my_obj` needs `operator->`.

Comment: @MooingDuck: ah, maybe `boost::iterator_facade` takes care of it. I didn't pay close enough attention, and I must admit I'm not familiar with Boost. If one writes a proxy-returning iterator by hand, then one should note that `o->friendly_name()` is interpreted as `(o.operator->())->friendly_name()`. So `my_iterator::operator->` must return something that's either a pointer, or an instance of a class that itself implements `operator->`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: I hadn't considered that, but the code works, so apparently boost is doing magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the boost page on iterator_facade, the template arguments are: derived iterator, value_type, category, **reference type**, difference_type.  Ergo, merely tell it that references are not references

```
class my_iterator 
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
        my_iterator,
        my_obj,
        boost::forward_traversal_tag,
        my_obj> //dereference returns "my_obj" not "my_obj&"
```

See it working here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b09ddc37068368b